# Command line utility to create screenshot

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

Is there some command line utility to create a screenshot of the my screen and store it as png? (Preferably one in the system, without need to install anything new)

Comment: May I ask why you need a command line utility instead of using the godly shortcuts for taking screen shots in OS X?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: I'd like to automate the process. I want to have screenshot per minute for 'screenshot journal'. (Like TimeSnapper, but on Mac).

Comment: in which case you can make an automator script that presses the keys

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: pressing the keys may interfere with my work. Simple shell script works great (https://gist.github.com/1306977), and I've added resizing to smaller image to save some space (using ImageMagick).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the command `screencapture`, which, according to [its `man` page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screencapture/), is to "capture images from the screen and save them to a file or the clipboard".

It's been a standard part of OS X since 10.2.